# How may I determine the optimal interval amplitude within a 1D dimension?

Tags: clustering

I have a 1D dataset where the unique dimension has a sample of 28.000 salaries. I'm looking to find how many classes should I use and what is the best amplitude interval to plot something like a normal distribution. I will use python and I'll try to solve the problem with Kernel Density Estimation. So, do you know a better option to find what I want?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the data? What is an optimal interval amplitude? What do you mean by `sample of 28.000 salaries`? Why are you talking about classes?

Comment: The data will likely not be normal at all (as there are no negative salaries), but rather log-normal or something else that is heavily skewed.